# How to add a domain user to a computer for first offline logon?

Tags: vpn, login, active-directory, windows-domain

I have a domain user to add to a PC to let he login for the first time remotely.
Is it possibile?

Usually only known users can log to the computer in offline mode, this is why usually I ask my users to login inside the local network for the first time before taking their PC home.

In this case the user is remote and he will logon for the first time remotely, to access VPN he will need to access to its account.

Is it possibile to transfer a domain user profile to the computer before the first login?

Comment: Is the remote computer already joined to the domain?

Comment: Yes it is already joined. But this user has never been logged to that computer

Comment: Does the user have a local login and a corporate VPN through which he can access the domain, then switch to the domain login?

Comment: I should create a local user just for this, is it the only solution? Is there no way to store locally by an administrator the authetication data to the computer?

Comment: It's just one idea, perhaps someone else can come up with another idea.